# Software to send BULK SMS from desktop using your mobile subscription

Tags: mobile

I have an Android mobile phone and my current subscription plan gives me unlimited SMS messages, needless to say I would like a more efficient framework to send multiple SMS at a time to groups/bulks of recipients / contacts on my phone.

A simple app / tool that for my desktop connected to the phone which lets me more easily write the SMS message together with selecting multiple reciepients at once is what I am looking for. One should think such a tool / app exists already, but I cannot seem to find any.

In reality I have a SMS that should be sent to 500+ recipients, and I would love for it to be able to send 160+ characters aswell in one SMS if needed just like the mobile phone would let me if I were to write each and every one manually.

Any ideas or recommodations for a possible sollution here?

Comment: I found a candidate here:
https://www.lantechsoft.com/help-bulk-sms-sender-2phones.html

Comment: Perhaps using [Google Messages](https://messages.google.com) and some other tools to interact with the browser might help.